# ng-show works but shows both divs quickly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, using an Angular.js controller I grab a result set from the database, the data is irrelevant. When the result comes back false (no rows found) the correct div shows "empty!".

When the result comes back true, the div "empty!" shows for a split second and then "results!" shows. The behavior reminds me of jQuery `.hide()`, I put my code below, but I still can't figure out why this behavior is happening?

HTML:

```
<h1 class="page-header">
    Products 
    <small>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right text-primary"></i> add
    </small>
</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div ng-show="categoriesFound">results!</div>
        <div ng-show="!categoriesFound">empty!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular controller:

```
mbpApp.controller('ProductsCtrl', function(httpService, $scope) {
    httpService.productCategoriesFindAll().then(function(d) {
    $scope.data = d;

        if(d.status) {
            $scope.categoriesFound = true;
        } else {
            $scope.categoriesFound = false;
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing by the `.row` and the `.col-` tags you're using Twitter Bootstrap. You only need the `.col-sm-12`, the other two are superfluous.

Comment: You are correct. Old habits die hard I guess.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because before you set `$scope.categoriesFound`, the template has to be processed. Angular expressions are forgiving of undefined but still report it as undefined, so the `results!` div's `ng-show` is false, and the `empty!` div's `ng-show` is !false, which is true.

You can resolve this by doing `$scope.categoriesFound = true;` at the beginning, but then that will show `results!` before you even get your response back.

Instead what you can do is add another variable (something like `categoriesLoading`), set that to true when you make the request, and add conditions in your templates to show some kind of loading indicator. When the request completes and is processed, set it to false and then populate the `categoriesFound` variable

Comment: You led me in the right direction. I wrapped those div's in a div with ng-show="show", set it to false and the called true after the conditional statement ran. It works but is ugly. Time to make it elegant. Thanks for the help and explanation.